# Error when Reverse Engineer Code First with EF Power Tools Beta 2 and VS2012 Update 1

Tags: entity-framework

Just trying to generate POCO objects, context etc for an existing database by using the EF Power Tools Beta 2 "Reverse Engineer Code First" facility.

I'm using VS2012 Ultimate with Update 1, on Windows 7 64 bit.

I point it at my existing database and hit OK.  I get the following error in my Build Output window:

> One or more errors occurred while processing template 'Entity.tt'.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude(1,4) : error : A processor named 'T4VSHost' could not be found for the directive named 'CleanupBehavior'. The transformation will not be run.  The following Exception was thrown:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find processor for directive 'T4VSHost'.
>      at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Utilities.EfTextTemplateHost.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ITextTemplatingEngineHost.ResolveDirectiveProcessor(String processorName)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessCustomDirectives(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, TemplateProcessingSession session, IEnumerable`1 directivesToBeProcessed)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you uninstall the Update by any change? I saw something like this because VS Update was installed. The fix was to repair VS.

Comment: No, but I have further news.  I tried it on my home PC when I got in.  That is running Windows 8 64 bit, Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. BUT WITH NO UPDATE 1.  I tried the reverse engineer without the Update 1 and it was fine.  Installed VS2012 Update 1 and *BANG* same error.  So it definitely looks to be caused by Update 1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like it is a confirmed issue with [Entity framework and Visual Studio 2012 update 1](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/769934/entityframework-bug-in-vs2012-update-1-ctp)

The link does currently contain 2 work arounds

Comment: To add to David's response below - the reported on connect was in the CTP but was fixed in the RTM. EF Power Tools are problem here - Even though the ouptut is the same the root cause is differnt

Comment: I can't even edit that EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude to remove the line. It won't let me edit that file..says access denied when I try to remove and save that line.

Comment: I had the same problem, notepad (or similar applications) doesnt allow you to edit read only files. You will need to save it to a different location (say desktop) and then copy it to the directory using windows explorer.

Comment: The workaround solved the issue for me as well, right click your favorite editor and ask to Run as Administrator so you can override it.

Answer (score 9):

This is a legitimate issue on the EF Power Tools, but it's not related to the CTP issue, which was resolved in the final VS Update release. A fix for the EF Power Tools is in the works.

David Obando

Entity Framework Team

Comment: Thanks for confirming David!  Is the workaround of removing that "clean" line still valid?  Or could that cause other issues?

Comment: I can't even edit that EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude to remove the line. It won't let me edit that file..says access denied when I try to remove and save that line.

Comment: can you post an estimated timeline on when you expect your team to deliver an updated vs extension?

Answer (score 0):

i also hit this same problem. The culprit was a package called Entity Framework Power Tool Beta 3. Updated this and everything was back to normal.