# Entity Framework Power Tools error when using Reverse Engineer Code First

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Sql Server 2012 database that I am trying to generate the Code First POCOs/Mappings in Visual Studio 2012 SP1 using the Reverse Engineer Code First option of EF Power Tools 2.

After setting the connection properties, the following error is generated. I have researched the web but with no luck on how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

> Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name
>   'EfTextTemplateHost' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I reinstalled EF Power Tools and got past this error. However I am getting this error below which seems to be a common one. It seems to be an issue of VS2012 SP1 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631738/error-when-reverse-engineer-code-first-with-ef-power-tools-beta-2-and-vs2012-upd).  A processor named 'T4VSHost' could not be found for the directive named 'CleanupBehavior'. The transformation will not be run.  The following Exception was thrown:
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find processor for directive 'T4VSHost'.

Comment: I believe this should be fixed in the http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/01/30/ef-power-tools-beta-3-available.aspx released today.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:
[EF Power Tools Beta 3 shipped today](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/01/30/ef-power-tools-beta-3-available.aspx) and the issue should be now fixed**

You will see this exception if you try using EF Power Tools after installing VS 2012 Update1.  [Rowan's response on EF Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/09/ef-power-tools-beta-2-available.aspx#10374587) (in the comments, towards the bottom of the page) reads:

*As a workaround to this issue you can edit Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude and remove the first line (<#@ CleanupBehavior Processor="T4VSHost" CleanupAfterProcessingTemplate="true" #>).
The only side effect of doing this is that the EF Designer will use more virtual memory when you create and edit models. On most computers this isn't a problem.*

We are working on shipping a new version of EF Power Tools which will include a fix for this problem.

**EDIT:
[Rowan's blog](http://romiller.com/2013/03/21/processor-named-t4vshost-could-not-be-found-for-the-directive-named-cleanupbehavior/) contains more details on how to manually work around the issue if you still hitting it even though you have Power Tools Beta 3 installed.**

Comment: Using ef power tools beta 3 and still seeing this =[  MS... sigh...  Edit:  Ran it again and it seems to be working.  Strange.

Comment: Still an issue as of May 17, 2013.  Sigh.

Comment: You shouldn't be. Make sure you have Beta3 installed. Also take a look at Rowan's post on this: http://romiller.com/2013/03/21/processor-named-t4vshost-could-not-be-found-for-the-directive-named-cleanupbehavior/. There are some steps you can try to fix this issue if you keep seeing the problem.

Comment: Still seeing this problem in Beta 4.  This is my first time using the power tools, and I reverse engineered a database to create some classes, and now my project won't compile because of this error.  Even if I remove the offending "*.tt" files, the project still thinks they are there and complains.  Also, compiler says The element 'entityFramework' has invalid child element 'providers'.  It seems to expect "contexts" instead.

Comment: I assume you are using VS2012. Have you installed VSUpdate1 or newer? Alternatively have you tried removing *just the line* which contains the CleanUpBehavior? If you are doing EF6 but don't have EF6 tooling installed the config is validated against EF5 schema config and hence the warnings. They are not harmful and can be ignored.

Comment: Still an issue in Beta 4.  It's also giving a warning saying that entityFramework has invalid child element 'providers' in web.config.  .NET Reflector shows the element is defined in the referenced EntityFramework.dll (for .NET Framework v4.5), so I shouldn't be getting the warning.  In any case, that "Error 1 Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'EfTextTemplateHost' could not be found." is still occurring, and none of the workarounds work for me, since my "*.tt" files don't reference T4VSHost at all. The corresponding "*.cs" files all contain the text "Error ".

Comment: Strange, I was editing my post and it reposted it after you replied.  I'm looking into it now.  Everything is up to date, so it's actually VS2012 Update 3.

Comment: There were no such lines mentioning "CleanUpBehavior" in the "*.tt" files, but I removed the line in the file that was in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes",

Comment: I don't understand the message on the blog that says "Note: You may see the following error after you add the templates. This is safe to ignore. It’s a result of Visual Studio trying to validate the templates… but they are never run from your project.  Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name ‘EfTextTemplateHost’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"  It's not OK to ignore it, because the main project DLL won't compile as long as that error is present.  In what DLL is EfTextTemplateHost defined anyway?

Comment: It seems to be working now, after restarting Visual Studio.  Perhaps upon initially installing PowerTools and running the reverse engineer database command, it has issues until Visual Studio is restarted.

Comment: I still can't find where EfTextTemplateHost is defined.  It would be helpful to be able to see what properties are available for editing the "*.tt" files, to add Column and Table attributes to the generated classes.  That gives me flexibility to run them through my own generic methods that read class instances directly from a SqlDataReader.

Answer (score -5):

Try to use this plugin
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=456117cf53a42144&id=456117CF53A42144%21388
(however it's not signed)
Someone complained @ MSDN that Power tools is screwed (actually whole EF is a mess).

After you install this one, when VS prompts you for database information click on "Advanced" and set Persist Security Info to True.

Should work

EF still got a crapload of bugs, avoid using it for critical environments. Don't even think about EF5.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion. Would be nice to see examples and things that can be tested rather sweeping statements like its crap. Have you tried ef 6?  What issues are troubling you with ef5?  I've not had problems beyond a dependency clash with enterprise library with unity.